# Add values to Session during testing (FakeRequest, FakeApplication)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to build some tests around a method that reads some data from the session.

I tried extending `FakeRequest` and overriding the `session` value, but I get an error on compilation saying that `session` has to be a `val` when overriden, which won't work.

How can I modify a `FakeRequest()` to add values to the session?

Comment: Did you indeed solve this by using the pull request from the accepted answer? Or did you find a way to achieve this without using a modified version of Play?

Comment: @arjan hi, no, i didn´t pull it, but I see that´s the solution. Expecting it to be integrated soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pull request about this functionality

See https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/103

Answer (score 4):

I used some examples from the pull request to build this in without using an updated version of play:

Create cookie:

```
val sessionCookie = Session.encodeAsCookie(Session(Map("key" -> "value")))
```

Create and execute fakeRequest:

```
val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET,"/").withHeaders(play.api.http.HeaderNames.COOKIE -> Cookies.encode(Seq(sessionCookie))))
```

Then to get stuff out I created the following:

Given the existing style of test methods:

```
status(result) must equalTo(OK)
```

I made:

```
def sessionCookie(result: Result): Option[Cookie] = cookies(result).get("PLAY_SESSION")
def session(result: Result): Session = Session.decodeFromCookie(sessionCookie(result))
```

Which you call:

```
  session(result).get("key") must be("value")
```

Have to say this is not tested in anger. But see if it helps.

Comment: this was useful when testing WithServer and WS.url(...) instead of FakeRequest