# Keep session in subsequent Java calls to Play 2.0's fakeRequest

Tags: java, scala, interop, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for a way to preserve the session when using Play 2.0's fakeRequest in my Java tests, but my attempts fail while invoking methods in the Scala-based JARs.

Based on a pull request mentioned in the Scala question [Add values to Session during testing (FakeRequest, FakeApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753654/add-values-to-session-during-testing-fakerequest-fakeapplication), I figured the following might work in Java:

```java
public Session getSession(Result result) {
  play.api.mvc.Cookies scalaCookies =
      play.api.test.Helpers.cookies(result.getWrappedResult());
  play.api.mvc.Cookie scalaSessionCookie =
      scalaCookies.get(play.api.mvc.Session.COOKIE_NAME()).get();
  scala.Option<play.api.mvc.Cookie> optionalCookie =
      scala.Option.apply(scalaSessionCookie);

  // Compiles fine, but fails with NoSuchMethodError:
  play.api.mvc.Session scalaSession =
      play.api.mvc.Session.decodeFromCookie(optionalCookie);

  return new play.mvc.Http.Session(Scala.asJava(scalaSession.data()));
}
```

This compiles just fine, but while running the tests it gets me:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  play.api.mvc.Session.decodeFromCookie(Lscala/Option;)Lplay/api/mvc/Session;
```

Being a total Scala newby, I really have no idea if I'm even close. The Scala Session [does expose (trait) that method through CookieBaker](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala), I *think*.

Note that I am not necessarily looking for a way to get the above code running; the above is really just the first (possible) step to get the session. Next I'd probably try to use something like `play.api.mvc.Session.encodeAsCookie(session)` to pass it to the subsequent requests. Like for [the ZenTasks demo](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks):

```java
@Test
public void testLoginAndMore() {
  Helpers.running(Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase()), 
  new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
      data.put("email", "guillaume@sample.com");
      data.put("password", "secret");

      Result result = 
        callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.authenticate(),
          fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(data));
      assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Status.SEE_OTHER);
      assertThat(redirectLocation(result)).isEqualTo("/");

      // All fine; we're logged in. Now somehow preserve the cookie. This
      // does NOT do the trick:
      Session session = getSession(result);
      // ...subsequent callAction(..)s, somehow passing the session cookie 
    }
  });
}
```

For 1.x, [Playframework Secure module: how do you “log in” to test a secured controller in a FunctionalTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762246/playframework-secure-module-how-do-you-log-in-to-test-a-secured-controller-in) helps, but things seem to have changed in 2.0, and I never used 1.x.

Comment: (Also added to [a related post in the Play Framework Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/session/play-framework/FuXaP7z9wz8); awaiting moderation. Will keep that in sync with this post, if applicable.)

Comment: In Google Groups, Peter Hausel just wrote: *Hi, I am going to push a fix for this today(alongside cookie and flash support). Thanks peter*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much magic needed after all. The following simply preserves the HTTP header that sets the cookies, and passes that in the next request:

```java
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("email", "guillaume@sample.com");
data.put("password", "secret");

Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.authenticate(),
  fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(data));

assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Status.SEE_OTHER);
assertThat(redirectLocation(result)).isEqualTo("/");
// All fine; we're logged in. Preserve the cookies:
String cookies = header(HeaderNames.SET_COOKIE, result);

// Fetch next page, passing the cookies
result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, redirectLocation(result))
  .withHeader(HeaderNames.COOKIE, cookies));

assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Status.OK);
assertThat(contentAsString(result).contains("Guillaume Bort"));
```

(See [the first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9906349/1) of this very answer for some information about getting only the `PLAY_SESSION` cookie, and parsing that. That's hardly needed though.)

Answer (score 4):

It's really easy with the current version of Play to use the session in your tests. You can use the `cookies(Result result)` static helper method.

```
// Route that sets some session data to be used in subsequent requests
Result result = callAction(...);
Http.Cookie[] cookies = FluentIterable.from(cookies(result)).toArray(Http.Cookie.class);

FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest(GET, "/someRoute").withCookies(cookies);
callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.requestNeedingSession(), request);
```